# Embedding application resources

Tags: c#, winforms, installation, embed, move

I have a C# Forms Application,

If i wanted to use the (debug).exe in the bin on other computers with the resource files embedded instead of having to make an installer how do i do so? (how do i embedd the resource files)

Also how do i add the path of the embedded resource files in the .exe?

Comment: Usually its just exe and all dll files but you should post more information about application such as what does it utilize before a better answer is given. SQL Data base ? XML files ? Any other external resources ?

Comment: @ Shenaniganz it is just a simple C# Forms app. The sources i want to embedd are .dll, .txt etc i am not actually using the files with the app just replacing these files with old ones.. Its kind of like an update.

Answer (score 0):

Select the file in the Solution Explorer, and then in the Properties Window, change the Build Action to Embedded Resource. The you change your code to get the embedded resource using code like the following:

```
     try
     {
         _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
         _imageStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyImage.bmp");
         _textStreamReader = new StreamReader(_assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyTextFile.txt"));
     }
     catch
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error accessing resources!");
     }
```

This code is from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292)

Comment: Thanks Michael this sorts how to embedd the files... However can i use this[code]                    //Move test.txt
                    if (File.Exists(@"C:\users\test.txt"))
                        {
                            File.Delete(@"C:\users\test.txt");
                        }
                    File.Move(WHATISTHERESOURCELOCATION, @"C:\users\test.txt");[/code] So how would i use the above and implement this? Thanks

Comment: You would not use File.Move as there is no file. Instead you would read the Stream as shown above and write that to a file.

Comment: so i added a folder in resources called "test" inside "test" thier is a app called test2.exe How do i use the above to delete c:\users\test.exe if it exists and then move test2.exe to c:\users\ ?    Basically my program removes old files and then replaces new files from the click of one button...